# Android OnClick fails every new project

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

First post. I'm following a few courses on Android programming so fairly new but not a complete newbie. I have a background in programming from long ago..

For some odd reason, older projects have the OnClick running fine but every project I created today, with either Genymotion or AVD the OnClick never fires even in the following barebone example I created.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/js1qh263vldte0z/deleteme.zip?dl=0

Here's the original project I'm working on which I can't even click on the buttons (as if there's a transparency in front or something).

If someone can explain why when I open older projects based on 22 everything works but running now on 23 (with 16 as backward) OnClick doesn't work that'd be very nice of you. Thanks!

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ca.shaarable.planetxerox.admin_add_products_hardware">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_tv_name"
        android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_tv_name"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_et_name"
        android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_et_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.65">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_tv_thumbnail"
        android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_tv_thumbnail"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_image"
        android:src="@drawable/igen5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_third"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_sublayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_CANCEL"
                android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_CANCEL"
                android:background="#F99F1C"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_ADD"
                android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_ADD"
                android:background="#2ABDBA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the code for the class:

```
package ca.shaarableapps.presssupport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdminAddPrinter extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener
{
private EditText printerName;
private ImageView printerThumbnail;
private Button cancelBtn, addBtn;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_add_printer);

    printerName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.admin_add_printer_et_name);
    printerThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.admin_add_printer_image);
    cancelBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.admin_add_printer_CANCEL);
    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.admin_add_printer_ADD);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Nooooooooooooo");
    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.admin_add_printer_ADD:
            addBtn.setText("Good Job");
            break;

    }
}
```

}

[This is the layout as seen by the user...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTLfi.jpg)

Comment: You're missing `setOnClickListener(this)` function for each `Button`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is here in you code.

```
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/admin_add_printer_ADD"
                android:text="@string/admin_add_printer_ADD"
                android:background="#2ABDBA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick" // add this line
               />
```

Comment: I wish I could remember everything... Thank you Kishu, that was it! Much appreciated.

Comment: @KishuDroid Of course this solution will work but it is not good idea. It will make your code more hard to read and modify in future

Comment: @Phan Van Linh :  
android:onClick has a major advantage in addition to being less code - it's part of a layout resource. The resource is selected at runtime depending on the current configuration of the device. Some parts of your UI might use different variants of the same layout depending on whether the device is in landscape/portrait mode, has a different screen size, etc. In a situation like this you can use onClick attributes on each element to wire things up appropriately rather than a lot of code to determine what elements are present at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `.setOnClickListener(this);` inside onCreate(...) method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  ...
  addBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping. That worked.  :)  However I still don't know why I can't use the recommended way (Implements   View.OnClickListener).

Comment: I don't know what you say `why I can't use the recommended way (Implements View.OnClickListener)`. can you explain more

Comment: Hi Phan, thank you for helping. I had omitted to tell the xml layout  onClick="onClick".

Comment: @Shaare I think my way is the correct way to handle onClickEvent than the anwser above :)